# string without point to decimal

Tags: c#

I have this string "45043". How can I convert it to decimal 450.43 (i want to use cultureinfo)

tks

Comment: Do you want to convert it to the datatype `decimal` or do you just want to parse the `string` and reformat it according to CultureInfo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string s = "45043";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s) / 100;
```

(I'm not really sure where `CultureInfo` comes into it. Do you want to convert the `decimal` back into a `string` or something like that?)

Comment: Better than Preet's at least, since it will work for numbers with more and less than 3 digits to the left of the decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have something like:

```
string x = "45043";
double num = Double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);
```

Just replace with the culture you want or derive it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Using CultureInfo?  You mean using commas in certain cultures and periods in others?

How about:

```
var str = "45043";
var strToDecimal = (decimal.Parse(str) / 100).ToString();
var strExplicit = (decimal.Parse(str) / 100).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat); // more explicit version of what's happening above.
```

Comment: Hard to tell what the exact question is, but your answer covers at least one possible interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

To show `TryParse` and use of `CultureInfo`

```
string input = "45053";
decimal result;

if (decimal.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
{
    result /= 100M;
}
else
{
    // invalid input, handle in whatever way you deem appropriate
}
```